# How To Insert Excel Table in HTML Body and send it via Gmail

Tags: html, excel, vba

I manged to create a code for sending e-mail via gmail using VBA code.
My next step, is to insert a range in HTML body. Can you help me with it?

Code :

```
    Sub Send_mail()
    Dim myMail As CDO.Message
    Set myMail = New CDO.Message

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxxx@xxxx.com"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "xxxxx"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update



Dim strHTML
strHTML = "<HTML>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<HEAD>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<BODY>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<b> This is the test HTML message body</b></br>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</BODY>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</HTML>"



With myMail
.Subject = "Position Match Check " & Now()
.From = "xxxx@xxxx.com"
.To = "xxxxk@xxxx.eu"
.TextBody = ""
.HTMLBody = strHTML


End With
On Error Resume Next

myMail.Send
MsgBox ("Mail Sent")

Set myMail = Nothing


End Sub
```

Range that I want to add to HTML body:

```
`Dim r As Range
 Set r = Range("B6:J88")
 r.Copy
 Dim p As Picture
 Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
 p.Cut`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to convert the table into html. [Have a look at this for an example](http://analystcave.com/excel-export-excel-to-html-convert-tables-html/)